# Apigee API to check if platform is alive

Tags: documentation, apigee

I know Apigee comes with several out of the box API to do deployments and query various pieces of information. Is there a lightweight out of the box API that we can give to our customers to verify if the APigee platform is still alive and running? This will prevent them from sending us API traffic when the system is unable to process it.

Answer (score 2):

*The following may be a good partial solution, but it really depends on how you intend to expose this information, where your monitoring server sits in the architecture, and what facilities you have to process/report status.  That said...*

Depending on what you define as 'lightweight', there is an option for **OPDK installations** to CURL on the following:

```
http://{management-server-ip}:8080/v1/servers
```

To check status, there is a field called **IsUp** (Boolean).  To get more specific, you can use the query parameter **type** so you can get back specific components.  The valid values are:

```
http://{management-server-ip}:8080/v1/servers/?type=app-datastore
http://{management-server-ip}:8080/v1/servers/?type=kms-datastore
http://{management-server-ip}:8080/v1/servers/?type=message-processor
http://{management-server-ip}:8080/v1/servers/?type=router
```

I don't believe this is possible on **Cloud** due to the nature of component resourcing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine whether Apigee is able to serve your own APIs, it might make sense to create a ping API call manually. You might want a couple of different flavors -- one that immediately turns around and responds from within Apigee (testing connectivity to the Apigee layer), and one that pings your backend servers (testing end to end connectivity). Anything out of the box wouldn't be able to ping your backend.

Answer (score 1):

What many customers do is create a "Health Check" API Proxy.

This can just be an Echo Server, which you can easily create by building an API Proxy with No Target.

In the *New API Proxy* tool, choose **(o) No Target**.  And that's it.

Then whatever data you pass to that proxy will be returned in the response.

For example:
$ curl http://{your-org}-{env}.apigee.net/v1/healthcheck -d "Hello"

Hello